# Call action which does not redirect

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a part of a page which should perform an operation (send data to the backend) and thereafter just remain on the current page.

What is the best way of doing this?

Do I do it using Ajax? Any more appropriate ways?

Comment: there are a number of ways you can send data back to the server, depends on your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I do it using Ajax?

AJAX is one way to achieve this. For example you could use jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Foo", "Bar")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { someValue: 'abc' },
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.message);
    }
});
```

which will send an Ajax request to the `Foo` action on the `Bar` controller. It will also pass along a `someValue` parameter:

```
public class BarController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Foo(string someValue)
    {
        // someValue will equal to abc here
        // TODO: do some processing and return some result

        return Json(new { message = "the data was successfully sent to the server" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remain on the current page sending an AJAX request is the way to go. I recommend using jQuery (www.jquery.com) to do so. If you're new to ajax requests take a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/